# PaperTrial versions handling changeset error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6, paper-trail-gem

here are my models looks like so I can address properly my issue

```
class Product

  has_paper_trail
  
  belongs_to :category

end
```

On my HTML side, I need to load all the logs using the PaperTrial versions. like this

```
@product.versions.each |version|
 version.changeset.each do |k, v|
   - if k.to_s == "category_id"
    - old_record = v[0].blank? ? " No Record " : Category.find(v[0].to_i).name
    - new_record = v[1].blank? ? " No Record " : Category.find(v[1].to_i).name
    = "Category" + " From: " + "#{old_record} " + " To: " + "#{new_record}"
```

in my HTML looks fine but. there is a scenario. that category will be deleted. and I will get an error in this view. because of my "Category.find". the find method cant find the Category that already deleted.

is there a way to store the name of the category and not the ID. so I can get rid of using "find"

or there is a better way to implement these things?

Comment: If you want to retain a history of deleted category data (e.g. the category name), then you should be soft-deleting the categories too. If the `products` table only stores `category_id`, and not the `category_name`, then you're not keeping a record of that data.

Comment: Of course, another option would be to denormalise the database - so `categories.name` is also stored in `products.category_name`. That's not ideal though, as now you need to duplicate information and worry about things like "what if the category changes name, then I need to update all these duplications of the data field elsewhere".

Comment: @TomLord can you give me an example so I can visualize thanks for the fast comment

Comment: @TomLord how to overwrite the ID of the category to category name?

Comment: My point was that you **COULD** have *two* database columns: `products.category_id` *and* `products.category_name`. This means the name would be stored into places, not one. On the plus side that's an easy way to store the product history, but on the downside you'd duplicating data - and there's a risk of values getting out of sync between the two tables.

Comment: *Or...* like I said, you need to soft-delete `categories` as well as `products`. That way you can still retrieve deleted category data, such as the name.

Comment: @TomLord what do you mean in soft-delete?

Comment: @DeezNuuts When a record is deleted via Active Record (the default ORM library packaged with Ruby on Rails), instead of actually deleting the record from the database, populate the deleted_at column with the time of deletion

Comment: @DeezNuuts if it is not necessary to show old record info then you can use try eg: Category.find(v[0].to_i).try(:name)

Comment: @Chandan i tried Category.find(v[0].to_i).try(:name) the error is Couldn't find id. is there another way to catch that error?

Comment: @DeezNuuts Normally when you delete something from a database, it is **gone**. Missing. Irretrievable. Deleted. However, by using the `paper_trail` library, you've essentially configured certain records to be *soft*-deleted: Because you're storing the *version history*, there's still a record of things that *used to exist*.

Comment: if you [read the README](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#4b-associations) for the library, you'll see there's actually a whole section about tracking deleted associations. There's even a [whole related project](https://github.com/westonganger/paper_trail-association_tracking) dedicated to the (complicated) feature. But essentially **you need to say `has_paper_trail` in the original model AND ALL ASSOCIATIONS(!!!!)** if you want to have any hope of restoring deleted association data.

Comment: That's what I meant by "soft-delete". If you're not saving anything about deleted records, like the `categories`, then you're never going to be able to fetch data within them - e.g. `Category#name`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend adding `category_name` attribute to your product model for caching.

```
# migration
rails g migration AddCategoryNameToProducts category_name

# Product model
  before_validation :cache_category_name
  def cache_category_name
    self.category_name = category&.name if category_name != category&.name
  end
```

But if you had already gone production, you **must fill** in the data first. And you are not able to fill data, that is already deleted.

```
# console or migration
Category.find_each(&:save!)
```

This scenario preserves the deleted category name, additionally it will be much more efficient than a lot of `Category.find`.

Or you can do some kind of soft-delete as others suggested.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. this enlighten me. but im just getting started to my Product model. how about another associations.  like has_many. i will do just like that????

Comment: That is one possibility. It is good for a few parameters. But if the project drifts you to a lot of these, maybe it is easier and better to create a soft-delete solution. So you only mark the model as deleted, but it is still present in your database. It may need more changes in your codebase, maybe even a new gem. It is quite a complicated topic. I'd start here: https://github.com/westonganger/paper_trail-association_tracking

Comment: thanks bro i will get back to your code later and read all the docu. ill need to rest. this project gives me covid